# Is there a process that is always running that uniquely identifiers a user in linux.

Tags: linux

Is there any such essential process launched in the user space...  ALso should take care of headless servers

Comment: what information are you looking for ? if someone is logged in or not ? If a user exists or not regardless logged in or not ? It is unclear. For every user who logs in to the system, you will see a shell process with this user's ownership, for starters.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I have a daemon running as root .. I have code in place to notify me of process creates and terminates. I am trying to see if I can reliably bank on a process  that would tell me if that's up and running or got created it means that a new user is in .. With bash they can launch multiple instances and do other things with it. Basically detects any logins and logouts. and I want to leverage my code that already notifies me of process creates and terminates.gnome would have been great but I can have a headless server as well then it wouldn't help me

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

There is no process you can be sure will be launched for any user, but logins are registered and you can see who is logged in with `w` (and several other commands can tell you too).